# Is it possible to return $count or $nextLink with function / action in CAP Java Odata service?

Tags: odata-v4, sap-cap

I have an OData service endpoint built with CAP Java that returns an array of objects. And because there is special data handling (filter for the last day/hour) the data is returned by a function. However, a consumer of this endpoint (SAC) is having problem because it requires $count for the returned array, which is absent in the response (no @count or @nextLink fields). Therefore, the question is whether it is possible to add @count and @nextLink into a response returned by a function in CAP Java?

I simulates the query from the tool: https://myhost/odata/v4/MonitoringService/dailyTaskCreateCommandsWithLifeCycles()?$count=true

And I got this error response

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "50008010",
        "message": "The query result misses a value for $count"
    }
}
```

200 response of this endpoint https://myhost/odata/v4/MonitoringService/dailyTaskCreateCommandsWithLifeCycles() as follows:

```json
{
    "@context": "$metadata#Collection(MonitoringService.CommandsWithoutUserData)",
    "@metadataEtag": "W/\"201af60104910da2489334b66e32c04a659f06f4125792608fe944d308336a79\"",
    "value": [
        {
            "ID": "aa5bc5f5-f8be-441f-bc81-a7ed353c1559",
            "dataType": "commandRequest",
            "runId": "aa5bc5f5-f8be-441f-bc81-a7ed353c1559",
            "runtimeId": "orch",
            "transformationAreaId": "df0bdb10-e275-4af2-bfa1-53fe847398be",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "eventType": null,
            "policy": null,
            "topic": null,
            "webhook": null,
            "lifeCycle": 1,
            "status": "finished",
            "createdAt": "2024-03-07T14:06:16.468843Z",
            "modifiedAt": "2024-03-07T14:09:28.697783600Z",
            "startTime": "2024-03-07T14:06:16Z",
            "endTime": "2024-03-07T14:09:28Z",
            "useCase": null
        },
        {
            "ID": "4e7b4318-adbe-4720-8fbd-cc6d830011c6",
            "dataType": "commandRequest",
            "runId": "4e7b4318-adbe-4720-8fbd-cc6d830011c6",
            "runtimeId": "orch",
            "transformationAreaId": "d9273be7-9f76-4355-8fd9-e108a7fe7dca",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "eventType": null,
            "policy": null,
            "topic": null,
            "webhook": null,
            "lifeCycle": 1,
            "status": "finished",
            "createdAt": "2024-03-07T13:56:13.947212300Z",
            "modifiedAt": "2024-03-07T14:13:47.126574800Z",
            "startTime": "2024-03-07T13:56:13Z",
            "endTime": "2024-03-07T14:13:47Z",
            "useCase": null
        }
}
```